# Git saves SSH in local project repository not in C:\Users\user-name/.ssh/id_rsa

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

I added a ssh key.

> ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "my email"
> Generating public/private rsa key pair.
> Enter file in which to save the key (C:\Users\user-name/.ssh/id_rsa):testkey 
> Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
> Enter same passphrase again: 
> Your identification has been saved in testkey.
> Your public key has been saved in testkey.pub.

I tried commands like `ls -al ~/.ssh` and `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to find it. Didn't help.
Than i created a .ssh folder in my user directory using `mkdir ${HOME}/.ssh` and tied to create another SSH key. I did it in VS Code so it told me

```
testkey already exists. 
Overwrite (y/n)?
```

Then i decided to `cat testkey.pub` and it returned me a key. Than i checked my local repo and found 2 files `testkey` and `testkey.pub`
So why it can't save in C:\Users\user-name/.ssh/id_rsa ?
I obviously don't want to store it my local project repo

I am still learning. Was watching [Course about Git](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RGOj5yH7evk&t=1483s) but got stuck on 22:00 with this problem

Comment: You seem to be mixing Windows and Unix/Linux command line commands.  I don't believe that the `~` is usable in the Windows world unless you're using WSL.  What if you do a `dir $HOME\.ssh`?

Comment: "Git" didn't save anything anywhere. `ssh-keygen` did; you just happened to have your Git repository as your working directory at the time.

Comment: You can simply copy the key pair to your `.ssh` directory after it's created.

Answer (score 1):

> Enter file in which to save the key (C:\Users\user-name/.ssh/id_rsa):testkey

You entered filename without full path so `ssh-keygen` saves the keypair in the current directory. The answer should be

```
Enter file in which to save the key (C:\Users\user-name/.ssh/id_rsa):C:\Users\user-name/.ssh/testkey
```

Or

```
C:
cd \Users\user-name\.ssh
ssh-keygen
Enter file in which to save the key (C:\Users\user-name/.ssh/id_rsa):testkey
```